# Convert statement level trigger to row level trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger on workson table where the trigger will update employee's total_budget when i try to insert into workson table. the below code works but i require to change this statement trigger into a row level trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateEmp
after INSERT
   ON workson
BEGIN
    FOR emp_l IN (select employee.e# AS employeeNo,sum(budget) AS totalbudget
                from employee left outer join workson
                on employee.e# = workson.e#
                left outer join project
                on workson.p# = project.p#
                group by employee.e#
                order by employee.e# asc)
    LOOP
        UPDATE employee
           SET total_budget = emp_l.totalbudget
         WHERE e# = emp_l.employeeNo;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I have tried using this trigger below but it doesn't work properly as the first insert committed doesnt happen until the next insert is committed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateEmp
after INSERT
   ON workson
for each row
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

    FOR emp_l IN (select employee.e# AS employeeNo,sum(budget) AS totalbudget
                from employee left outer join workson
                on employee.e# = workson.e#
                left outer join project
                on workson.p# = project.p#
                group by employee.e#
                order by employee.e# asc)
    LOOP
        UPDATE employee
           SET total_budget = emp_l.totalbudget
         WHERE e# = emp_l.employeeNo;
    END LOOP;
commit;
END;

insert into workson(e#,p#,hours)
values('00187','1005',20);
commit;
insert into workson(e#,p#,hours)
values('00187','1006',20);
commit;
```

Comment: `budget` is a column of which table??? why `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` is used??

Comment: budget is a column of project table which has the projectNo, the project name and the budget. the table WorksOn links the employee table and the project table hence the join statement. I've only used PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION as an attempt to change to a row level trigger rather than a statement level

Comment: Why would you want this as a row-level trigger?  You just make it repeat the operation many times instead of doing it once. Unless you meant to restrict to a single employee in the cursor (which you don't).  In any case, writing a row-level trigger that accesses the same table as the trigger fires on is strictly to be avoided. You have used an autonomous transaction to work around the "table is mutating" error, but that just causes you another issue as you have mentioned.

Comment: thanks Tony, honestly it was an assignment question requirement and i found it weird that i have to use a row trigger when a statement trigger could work the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a row level trigger it will have, by definition, there is a single E# and budget hours, which is sufficient for updating employee. The select for budget is not required. Just update employee directly.

```
create or replace trigger 
after insert
   on workson
for each row
declare
begin
    update employee
       set total_budget = total_budget + :new.budget 
     where e# = :new.e#;
end ;
```

You do not want AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION. What happens when you update employee in the trigger and commit that, then the insert that fired the trigger is rolled back. That update of employee is still committed.  
Now from an instructor's point of view perhaps the intent of the assignment being to show the data requirements and availability between them.